# How define a response with two schemas objects

Tags: openapi

I have two schemas objects:

'#/components/schemas/customer'
'#/components/schemas/account'

Is there are way we can define post response body with both '#/components/schemas/customer' and '#/components/schemas/account' using open API 3.0 specs

Answer (score 5):

This depends on the use case.

1) If the response is either `customer` or `account`, use `oneOf`:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A `customer` object or an `account` object
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/customer'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/account'
                # Example for Swagger UI - see the note below
                example:
                  foo: bar
```

**Note for Swagger UI users:** Currently Swagger UI [does not generate examples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3803) from `oneOf` schemas. The workaround is to provide a custom `example` alongside `oneOf`.

2) If the response has a combined set of properties from `customer` and `account`, use `allOf`:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'

components:
  MyResponse:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/customer'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/account'
```

3) If the response has two properties, one of which is a `customer` object and another is an `account` object, use the following:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'

components:
  MyResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      customer:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/customer'
      account:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/account'
```